# read a json column into new columns pandas

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column like this in pandas dataframe and I want to convert it to multiple columns a,b,c,d

```
{"a":false,"b":false}
{"a":false,"b":false,"c":true}
nan
{"a":false}
{"a":true,"d":true}
```

I tried:

```
ops = ops.join( pd.DataFrame(json.loads(d)  for d in ops.pop('json_column')) )
```

but it creates columns with names(a,b,c,d) and doesn't put values into it. All values are nan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working your solution with `if-else` statement for handle missing values and also is added `[]` with `index` parameter:

```
ops = ops.join(pd.DataFrame([json.loads(d) 
                             if pd.notna(d) 
                             else {} 
                             for d in ops.pop('json_column')], index=ops.index))
print (ops)
       a      b     c     d
0  False  False   NaN   NaN
1  False  False  True   NaN
2    NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN
3  False    NaN   NaN   NaN
4   True    NaN   NaN  True
```